# How do I get Maven to work in RHEL 7.x when there are MojoExecutor errors?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I was doing something with Maven and I got an error.  I think the way to fix this problem is to have a `mvn clean install` work properly.  Off hand, I see now reason why this command would not work properly.

I am running RedHat 7, Maven 3.5, and Java 1.8.  I am in this directory: `/usr/bin/incubator-metron/`
As root I run `mvn clean install -X`

I got this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18:test
>   (integration-tests) on project metron-maas-service: There are test
>   failures. [ERROR] [ERROR] Please refer to
>   /usr/bin/incubator-metron/metron-analytics/metron-maas-service/target/surefire-reports
>   for the individual test results. [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18:test
>   (integration-tests) on project metron-maas-service: There are test
>   failures.
>
> Please refer to
>   /usr/bin/incubator-metron/metron-analytics/metron-maas-service/target/surefire-reports
>   for the individual test results.
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)

How do I fix this?

I want "mvn clean install" to work.  Maybe I do not know what directory to run this command from.  I did research.  In /usr/bin/incubator-metron/pom.xml I added these lines (near the other dependencies):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

That had no effect.  I therefore deleted the lines.

I looked at this file: `/usr/bin/incubator-metron/metron-analytics/metron-maas-service/target/surefire-reports/org.apache.metron.maas.service.MaasIntegrationTest.txt`

I saw it had this info:

> Test set: org.apache.metron.maas.service.MaasIntegrationTest
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed:
>   471.533 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.apache.metron.maas.service.MaasIntegrationTest
>   testMaaSWithoutDomain(org.apache.metron.maas.service.MaasIntegrationTest)
>   Time elapsed: 238.072 sec  <<< FAILURE! java.lang.AssertionError
>           at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
>           at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
>           at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
>           at org.apache.metron.maas.service.MaasIntegrationTest.testDSShell(MaasIntegrationTest.java:234)
>           at org.apache.metron.maas.service.MaasIntegrationTest.testMaaSWithoutDomain(MaasIntegrationTest.java:110)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's just failing because you have unit test failures. To ignore tests you can run

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```